# How to update database with local files for LaTeX in MiKTeX 2.9?

Tags: miktex2.9

When adding a local folder to the database, for example for custom .sty files, in former versions of MiKTeX one would then update the database so that LaTeX finds new files there. However, I did not find anything like this in the "Console" of MiKTeX 2.9 and LaTeX does not find my newly added files.

Comment: menu "tasks" -> refresh file name data base.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thanks. The new user interface is so easy to use that I forgot the Console even had any menus to check. Maybe there could be a button for this on the Directories tab...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a "Refresh File Name Database" entry in the "Tasks" Menu, as Ulrike pointed out correctly in her comment that I overlooked.